# Query doesn't run after if statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

At my work, we have a module/web application that queries our DB looking for students that have RSVP'd to live with us again (we are Housing & Dining) - either in our Apartments or Residence Halls. The current application takes a long time to run and I have been asked to optimize by giving the user an option to select whether the students in question are residents of our apartments (Jardine below) or if they live in the dorms. I have a basic if statement that structures the query based on the selection from an html select menu, and then runs the query with the builded sql statement. For some reason, when I implement this change - no results are returned. Any help is appreciated! We are running 3 queries total, one main query that grabs all residents, another to check for an "intent to vacate (ITV)" which are only applicable to the jardine residents, and one more that is applicable to all of them.

```
try
{       
    if (isset($_POST['select'])) 
    {
        if ($_POST['select'] == 'jardine') 
        {
            $jardine = true;    // Neighborhood and Apartments include the Jardine under 'Site_name' column
            $query = "SELECT * FROM av_user_hms_PatronAssignments a WHERE NOW() BETWEEN ElementStart AND ElementEnd 
                    AND a.Site_name LIKE '%Neighborhood% AND a.Site_name LIKE '%Apartments%'
                    ORDER BY Last_Name, First_Name";
        }
        else
        { 
            $jardine = false;   // Everything else is Residence Halls
            $query = "SELECT * FROM av_user_hms_PatronAssignments a WHERE NOW() BETWEEN ElementStart AND ElementEnd 
                    AND a.Site_name NOT LIKE '%Neighborhood% AND a.Site_name NOT LIKE '%Apartments%'
                    ORDER BY Last_Name, First_Name";
        }

        $hms = new hms_helper();

        // Run the query
        $hmsRows = $hms->query_a($query);           

        //see if user has completed RSVP application
        $query = "SELECT * FROM rsvp.application WHERE wid = ? AND termID = ?";
        $apps = $mysqli->prepare($query) or throwNewException("Prepare error:".$mysqli->error." ".$query);
        $term = getCurrentTerm();
        $apps->bind_param("ii", $stmtArg,$term);


        if ($jardine)
        {           
            // also check Jardine Intent to Vacate
            $query = "SELECT * FROM ITV.ITV WHERE WID = ? AND STR_TO_DATE(vacate_date,'%m/%d/%Y') > '".date("Y")."-01-01';";
            $itv = $eITV->prepare($query) or throwNewException("Prepare error:".$eITV->error." ".$query);
            $itv->bind_param("i", $stmtArg);
        }

        foreach($hmsRows as $k=>$a)
        {
            //$lastWID is used to keep track of last wid so that no entry is duplicated
            $stmtArg = (int)$a["wid"];
            $apps->execute();
            $appResult = $apps->get_result();// get the result back

            if ($jardine)
            {
                $itv->execute();
                $itvResult = $itv->get_result();
                if($itvResult->num_rows > 0) // if they are planning to leave jardine unset them
                {
                    unset($hmsRows[$k]);
                } 
            }

            if($appResult->num_rows > 0) // if they have an application unset them
            {
                unset($hmsRows[$k]);// removes this entry from the array so it won't be displayed.
            }
            elseif($a['ID_Number'] == $lastWID)// don't show duplicates
            {
                unset($hmsRows[$k]);
            }               
            $lastWID = $a['ID_Number'];
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Everything within hms_helper class work correctly
- I have run the queries with our ODBC query tool and those all work
- The $_POST['select'] is being passed correctly, I have had a few echo statements to check this
- The execute call is what runs the queries for $itv and $apps (prepared)

Comment: You keep setting `$query` and then not using it before setting it again...

Comment: i dont know what `$jardine` means but if it is false, you never run some of the queries..?

Comment: I'm binding the query to $apps and $itv, the only other one to run is the main query that grabs all of them - which runs before preparing the others.

Comment: True, If $jardine is false then that query is obsolete